# Right align battery and clock in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

So I've got battery status and clock in emacs mode line:

> (display-battery-mode 1)
>
> (display-time-mode 1)

Anyway I could align them to the left side of the mode line?

Answer (score 1):

Not easily.

Both `display-battery-mode` and `display-time-mode` operate by modifying [`global-mode-string`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Variables.html). You can try removing the appropriate objects from the latter and adding them to `mode-line-format` in the left-most place, but I don't think this is a good use of your time.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need other information of mode-line, you can do like this. Please take this just as an example of customizing mode-line.

```
(setq-default mode-line-format
    '("" battery-mode-line-string display-time-string)
)
```

Result:

[image]